# Всегда ли Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) возвращает положительное число?

Tags: java

Всегда ли такой код возвращает положительное число?

```
Math.abs(new Random().nextInt())
```

Comment: Необязательно, может вернуть ноль

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`Math.abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) возвращает абсолютное значение переданного числа, простыми словами - его модуль. А модуль, как известно, больше либо равен нулю.

То есть, вне зависимости от того, какое число вернёт `new Random().nextInt()`, результат также будет больше либо равен нулю.

---

Единственный частный случай, в котором `Math.abs()` может вернуть отрицательное число в вашем примере - это если `new Random().nextInt()` вернёт `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Почему это происходит?

Вот метод `Math.abs()`:

```
public static int abs(int a) {
    return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
}
```

Если мы передадим `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, то метод вернёт `-Integer.MIN_VALUE`, но мы оперируем с `int`, и минимальное возможное `int`-число (как раз `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) - это `0x80000000`.

Что же получится при попытке взять `-Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Заметим, что `-x` эквивалентно `(~x)+1`.

Тогда:

```
-(Integer.MIN_VALUE) = (~(0x80000000)) + 1 = 0x7FFFFFFF + 1 
                     = 0x80000000 = Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Как видите, вернётся опять `Integer.MIN_VALUE` - вот поэтому и получается так, что может быть возвращено отрицательное число.

Почитайте про это, аналогичный вопрос уже был задан: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444611/math-abs-returns-wrong-value-for-integer-min-value).

---

Аналогично и с остальными: `Long.MIN_VALUE`, `Double.MIN_VALUE` и так далее.

Comment: Если `new Random().nextInt()` вернет `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, то `Math.abs(...)` вернет `-2147483648`.

Comment: @post_zeew это единственный и частный случай, если верить гуглу :)